# Absolute/conditional convergence problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to determine whether $\sum_{n=1} ^\infty (-1)^n \frac{3n}{\sqrt(n^3 + 2)}$ is absolutely convergent, conditionally convergent, or if it diverges.

Thus far, I've shown that $\sum_{n=1} ^\infty (-1)^n \frac{3n}{\sqrt(n^3 + 2)}$ converges, and I'd like to show that it's absolute value $\sum_{n=1} ^\infty \frac{3n}{\sqrt(n^3 + 2)}$ diverges to show that the original series is conditionally convergent (assuming that I am write in that assumption).

I am trying to use the Comparison Test to show this. However, when I consider

$\frac{3n}{\sqrt{n^3 + 2}} < \frac{3n}{\sqrt{n^3}} = \frac{3}{\sqrt{n}}$, which diverges, it doesn't help me since it is greater than the original series and diverges. Similarly, $\frac{3}{\sqrt{n^3 + 2}} < \frac{3n}{\sqrt{n^3 + 2}}$, and converges. Neither of these are conclusive by the Comparison Test. Am I approaching this incorrectly, or does anyone have a suggestion on how else to apply the Comparison Test?

Answer (score 0):

Good job on the first step. The second step can be completed by using $\sqrt{n^3+2}<n^2$ for $n>1.$